# Java using if(search) == with multiple classes giving error search cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to use multiple classes with arrays for the first time which interact with each other and I am having trouble getting my program to work.

My intention is in Employee.java you enter the ID and details of an employee through addEmployee(), then run addQual(); which is in Qualification.java which adds qualifications to the employee.

```
 if(search == Employee.idArray)
  return;
```

I am trying to use the above code for addQual(); to retrieve the ID of the employee from Employees.java but it does not work. I get the following error:
Qualification.java  [line: 28] Error: search cannot be resolved to a variable

I am stuck at this point and not making much progress help and insight would be greatly appreciated thanks.

**Employee.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee
{
  final static int MAX=20;
  public static String [] firstnameArray= new String[MAX];
  public static String [] lastnameArray= new String[MAX];
  public static String [] positionArray= new String[MAX];
  public static int [] salaryArray= new int[MAX];
  public static int [] idArray= new int[MAX];
  public static int count=0;

  public static void add(int id, String fname, String lname, String position, int salary)
  {
    idArray[count] = id;
    firstnameArray[count] = fname; 
    lastnameArray[count] = lname; 
    positionArray[count] = position; 
    salaryArray[count] =  salary; 
    ++count;
  }

  public static void addEmployee()
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);      
    for(int i=0; i<idArray.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter employee id as an integer");
      System.out.print(" (0 to finish): ");
      int id = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      if (id==0)
        return;

      System.out.println("Enter employee First name");

      String fname = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter employee Last name");

      String lname = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter employee position");

      String position = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter employee yearly salary");

      int salary = sc.nextInt();

      add(id, fname, lname, position, salary);
    }
```

**Qualification.java**

```
   import java.util.*;

public class Qualification{

  final static int MAX=20;
  public static String[] qNamearray = new String[MAX];
  public static int[] employeeIdarray = new int[MAX];
  public static int[] qDurationarray = new int[MAX];
  public static int count = 0;

   public static void add(int employeeId, String qName, int qDuration)
  {
    employeeIdarray[count] = employeeId;
    qDurationarray[count] = qDuration; 
    qNamearray[count] = qName; 
    ++count;
  }

   public static void addQual()
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);      
    for(int i=0; i<employeeIdarray.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter employee id as an integer");
      System.out.print("  (0 to finish): ");
      int employeeId = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      if(search == Employee.idArray)
      return;

      System.out.println("Enter employee qualification");

      String qName = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter employee qualification duration");

      int qDuration = sc.nextInt();

      add(employeeId, qName, qDuration);
    }
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: You never declared a variable `search`, so what do you expect to happen here?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Any errors? What is the expected result? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry the error is Qualification.java  [line: 28]
Error: search cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Your static variables kind of defeat the purpose of OOP. Wouldn't it be easier for you if you made some kind of a list which stores instances of an Employee.

Comment: The error says it all i guess `search cannot be resolved to a variable`, declare `search`!

Comment: Please do not use arrays, use collections such as `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(search == Employee.idArray)
  return;
```

The above code does not seem to be doing any useful logical branching (it just exits from the method without any logging/message which is not recommended). Also, there is no `search` variable declared, hence the error.

I would advice removing this code block and re-running the method.